# excel vba table query connection properties

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to display the properties of all tables in a workbook. The code I am using is working but I am missing some information. As a matter of fact, some of the queries attached do not match the real query being used by the table

Below is the entire code used (the module wb parameter is a parameter from a user form list box)

```
Public Sub WbkConnProperties(wb As Workbook)

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim objWBConnect As WorkbookConnection
Dim vWs() As String
Dim lOffset As Long
Dim lastr As Long, lastc As Long
Dim wsnm As String
Dim i As Long
Dim iex As Byte
'On Error Resume Next

'make sure we have at least one visible sheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
With ThisWorkbook
'For Each ws In .Worksheets
'  If Not ws.Name = .Worksheets(1).Name Then
'    ws.Delete
'  End If
'Next ws

ReDim vWs(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

i = 0
For Each WS In .Worksheets
vWs(i) = WS.Name
i = i + 1
Next WS

wsnm = Left(wb.Name, 20) & Right(wb.Name, 5)
iex = 0
For i = LBound(vWs, 1) To UBound(vWs, 1)
  If vWs(i) = wsnm & "_" & iex Or vWs(i) = wsnm Then
    iex = iex + 1
  End If
Next i

If iex > 0 Then
.Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Name = wsnm & "_" & iex
Set WS = .Worksheets(wsnm & "_" & iex)
Else
.Worksheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
.Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count).Name = wsnm
Set WS = .Worksheets(wsnm)
End If

End With 'thisw
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False

With WS.Range("A1:G1")
.Value = Array("Worksheet name", "Connection Name", _
"Data file source", "Sql Query text", "Data file path", _
"Connection String", "Connection Type")
End With

'________________________________________________________________________
'___
'___ col.1 - 0 - Nom de la feuille où se trouve le résultat de la requête
'___ col.2 - 1 - Nom de la connection relative à la feuille col.1
'___ col.3 - 2 - Nom du classeur des données sources (si applicable)
'___ col.4 - 3 - Requête sql
'___ col.5 - 4 - Chemin du classeur des données sources
'___ col.6 - 5 - Propriétés de la connection
'___ col.7 - 6 - Type de la connection (pour info. ce code peut
'___ s'appliquer pour les TCD)
'________________________________________________________________________

'ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
With WS
With .Range("A1")
lOffset = 0
For Each objWBConnect In wb.Connections
  lOffset = lOffset + 1
  .Offset(lOffset, 0).Value = "nom_feuille"
  .Offset(lOffset, 1).Value = objWBConnect.Name

  .Offset(lOffset, 2).Value = "classeur_donnees_src"
  .Offset(lOffset, 6).Value = objWBConnect.Type

  If objWBConnect.Type = xlConnectionTypeODBC Then
    .Offset(lOffset, 3).Value = objWBConnect.ODBCConnection.CommandText
    .Offset(lOffset, 5).Value = objWBConnect.ODBCConnection.Connection
    .Offset(lOffset, 2).Value = FWorkbookName(.Offset(lOffset, 5).Value)
    .Offset(lOffset, 4).Value = FWorkbookPath(.Offset(lOffset, 5).Value)

    .Offset(lOffset, 0).Value = GetRange(wb, .Offset(lOffset, 1).Value)


  ElseIf objWBConnect.Type = xlConnectionTypeOLEDB Then
    .Offset(lOffset, 5).Value = objWBConnect.OLEDBConnection.Connection
  Else
    .Offset(lOffset, 5).Value = "Not Applicable"
  End If
Next objWBConnect
End With


lastr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastc = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

With .Cells
  .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
  .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

  .Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
  .Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 40
  .Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 40
  With .Columns("D:D")
  .ColumnWidth = 75
  .Replace What:="`", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
  End With
  .Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 50
  .Columns("E:E").WrapText = True
  .Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 80
  .Columns("F:F").WrapText = True
  With .Columns("G:G")
  .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
  .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
  .EntireColumn.AutoFit
  End With

  With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lastc))
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .RowHeight = 25
    .Font.Bold = True
  End With
  With .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastr, lastc))
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .WrapText = True
  End With

  With .Columns("G:G")
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
  End With

End With 'ws

End Sub

Function FWorkbookName(mStr As String)

Dim fstr As Variant, fstrB As Variant
Dim FWstr As String
'Debug.Print mStr

fstr = Split(mStr, ";")
fstrB = Split(fstr(2), "\")

FWstr = fstrB(UBound(fstrB, 1))

FWorkbookName = FWstr

End Function

Function FWorkbookPath(mStr As String)

Dim fstr As Variant, fstrB As Variant
Dim FWstr As String
'Debug.Print mStr

fstr = Split(mStr, ";")
FWstr = Right(fstr(3), Len(fstr(3)) - 11)

FWorkbookPath = FWstr

End Function



Public Function GetRange(wbk As Workbook, ByVal sListName As String) As String

Dim oListObject As ListObject
'Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet

'Set wb = ThisWorkbook
sListName = Replace(sListName, " ", "_")
sListName = "Tableau_" & sListName

For Each WS In wbk.Sheets
    For Each oListObject In WS.ListObjects
        If oListObject.Name = sListName Then
            GetRange = WS.Name & vbCrLf & "[" & Replace(oListObject.Range.Address, "$", "") & "]"
        Exit Function
        End If
    Next oListObject
Next WS

Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
'For Each conn In wbk.Connections
'  Debug.Print conn.Name
'Next conn

End Function
```

Any ideas?

IG Data analyst

edit 1

drop box photo link (no account needed) there you can see the resulting screen. It shows in yellow the worksheet name and the corresponding table query. The stakeholder wants things to exactly match (the worksheet with the corresponding query).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9e6D.png)

The reason for the connection not matching the worksheet name that appears on the row is that the person who first worked on this workbook first changed many times over queries after creating query tables.

Comment: Ideas  -  Come up with what you are awaiting as a result. Then tell what you get as a result. Then say why do you think it is different.

Comment: This is a print screen of the output https://www.dropbox.com/s/aikn6jzebivwtww/Capture.PNG?dl=0 , there you can see the worksheet name in the first column doesn't always match the connection name in the second column (I matched colors to show results as simply as I could) - thanks